# misconfiguration of certificate's cn and virtual name. the certificate cn has example.com. we expected anotherexample.com as virtual name

Tags: apache, configuration, certificate

I am getting this error, when I am redirecting my html page to my customized module in apache.
When I click on the submit button, then the data is send to the module by apache server.
Then in my module.c I have ap_get_client_block to get the data from client block(data sent from the html page.)
after geting the data from the client this module.c, I am just displaying the data back to the browser as response from the apache server/my module.

As response I can see  "User input: 4:07.553498 2023] [:error] [pid 6470] Miscon6473ration o"
the pid 6470 when checked in the error_log for apache shows :

1. [Mon Apr 17 01:24:07.553498 2023] [:error] [pid 6470] Misconfiguration of certificate's CN and virtual name. The certificate CN has localhost4.localdomain4. We expected localhost.localdomain as virtual name.
   2.[suexec:notice] [pid 6470] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
   and 6473 in Misc----ration shows
2. [Mon Apr 17 01:24:07.724465 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6473] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) mod_auth_gssapi/1.5.1 mod_nss/1.0.14 NSS/3.28.4 PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
3. [Mon Apr 17 01:24:07.724529 2023] [core:notice] [pid 6473] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd'
4. [Mon Apr 17 01:24:07.622086 2023] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 6473] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor

Comment: I have solved this issue by adding the localhost4.localdomain4 as the servername in the httpd.conf file